# Compute integral of general form $ \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)^n d x $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I encountered the following integral and can't compute its value in general:
$$
I_n = \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)^n d x
$$
where $n\in \mathbb N$.

From integral tables/mathematica, I know that

$$I_1 = \frac{\pi^2}  4,\>\>\>\>\>I_2 = \frac{\pi^2}6$$

But, for general $n\in\mathbb N$, I don't know the result though. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect a general solution would have to start with$$\begin{align}I_n&=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{2xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}}\right)^ndx\\&=2^n\sum_{k\ge0}\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-(n+2k)x}\frac{(-1)^k(-n)_k}{k!}dx\\&=n!2^n\sum_{k\ge0}(n+2k)^{-n-1}\binom{n+k-1}{k}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Perhaps relevant: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)^{2n}\, dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\Gamma(k+n)}{k^{2n+1}\Gamma(1+k-n)}$$ and $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)^{2n-1}\, dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2n-1}(2n-1)\Gamma(-1+k+n)}{(2k-1)^{2n}\Gamma(1+k-n)}$$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the integral of the general form

$$
J_{n,m} = \int_0^\infty x^n \text{csch}^{m}x \>\mathrm{d}x
$$

and note that

$$
I_n = \int_0^\infty \Big(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\Big)^n d x= J_{n,n}
$$

As shown below, $ J_{n,n}$ can be computed via the reduction formula

$$J_{n,m}=\frac{n(n-1)}{(m-1)(m-2)}J_{n-2,m-2}
- \frac{m-2}{m-1} J_{n,m-2}\tag1
$$
along with the starting values
$$J_{2k-1,1}= \frac{(2^{2k}-1)(2k-1)!}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k),\>\>\>\>\>
J_{2k,2}=\frac{k(2k-1)!}{2^{2k-2}}\zeta(2k)\tag2
$$
$$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6, \>\>\>\zeta(4)= \frac{\pi^4}{90},\>\>\>
\zeta(6)=\frac{\pi^6}{945},\>\>\>\zeta(8)= \frac{\pi^8}{9450}, \>\>\>\cdots
$$

---

Proof: Apply
$$\int \text{csch}^{m}x\>\mathrm{d}x
= -\frac{\text{csch}^{m-2}x \>{\coth}x  }{m-1} -\frac{m-2}{m-1} \int \text{csch}^{m-2}x\>\mathrm{d}x
$$

to integrate $J_{n,m}$ by parts
$$J_{n,m} = \frac{n}{m-1} \int x^{n-1} \text{csch}^{m-2}x \coth x \mathrm{d}x- \frac{m-2}{m-1}J_{n,m-2}\tag3
$$
where
$$ \int x^{n-1} \text{csch}^{m-2}x \coth x \mathrm{d}x
=-\int x^{n-1} \text{csch}^{m-3}x \>d(\text{csch}x)\overset{IBP} = \frac{n-1}{m-2}
I_{n,m-2} $$

Plug into (3) to obtain the reduction formula (1). To evaluate
$J_{2k-1,1}$ and $ J_{2k,2}$ given in (2), apply the substitution $x=-\ln t$. Then
$$J_{2k,2}= 4\int_0^1 \frac{t \ln^{2k}t}{(1-t^2)^2}dt\overset{t^2\to t}=\frac1{2^{2k-1} }\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2k}t}{(1-t)^2}dt\\
\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac k{2^{2k-2} }\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2k-1}t}{1-t}dt
=\frac{k(2k-1)!}{2^{2k-2}}\zeta(2k)
$$

$$J_{2k-1,1}= -2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2k-1}t}{1-t^2}dt
=\frac{(2^{2k}-1)(2k-1)!}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k)
$$

---

Displayed below are some results via the reduction formulae (1) and (2):

\begin{align}
I_1 =J_{1,1} &= \frac32 \zeta(2)= \frac{\pi^2}4\\
I_2 =J_{2,2} &= \zeta(2)= \frac{\pi^2}6\\
I_3 =J_{3,3} &= 3J_{1,1}-\frac12 J_{3,1} = 3\cdot \frac{\pi^2}4 - \frac12 \cdot \left(\frac{45}4 \zeta(4)\right)
 = \frac{3\pi^2}4 - \frac{\pi^4}{16}\\
I_4 =J_{4,4} & = 2J_{2,2}-\frac23 J_{4,2} = 2\cdot \frac{\pi^2}6 - \frac23  \cdot \left(3\zeta(4)\right)
 = \frac{\pi^2}3 - \frac{\pi^4}{45}\\
I_5 =J_{5,5} 
& = \frac53 J_{3,3}-\frac34\left( 10J_{3,1} -\frac12J_{5,1} \right)
= \frac{5\pi^2}4 - \frac{25\pi^4}{24} +\frac{3\pi^6}{32}\\
 I_6 =J_{6,6} 
&= \frac32 J_{4,4}-\frac45 \left( 5J_{4,2} -\frac23 J_{6,2} \right)
= \frac{\pi^2}2 - \frac{\pi^4}{6} +\frac{4\pi^6}{315} \\
I_7 =J_{7,7} &=\>\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: I corrected the spelling of "formuli" to the correct "formulae". Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @K.defaoite - appreciate the correction

Answer (score 10):

**Claim:** for each positive integer $n$, $I_n$ is a linear combination of $\zeta(2),\zeta(4) \dots \zeta(2\left \lceil{n/2}\right \rceil )$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  The coefficients can be computed explicitly. More precisely,

$$I_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}m\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A_{j}^n\zeta(2j+2), &  \textrm{if } n=2m,\\
2(2m+1)\sum_{j=0}^{m}A_j^n(1-1/2^{2+2j})\zeta(2j+2), & \textrm{if } n=2m+1,  \end{array} 
\right.$$
where $A^n_j$ are integers determined by
$$(x+2m-1)\cdots (x+m+1)\widehat{(x+m)}(x+m-1)\cdots (x+1)=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A^n_j(x+m)^{m-2j-2}$$
if $n=2m$; and
$$2^{2m}(x+2m)(x+2m-1)\cdots (x+2)(x+1)=\sum_{j=0}^{m}A_j^n (2x+2m+1)^{2m-2j},$$
if $n=2m+1$.

**Examples:**
$$\begin{array}{ll}I_6&=3(\zeta(2)-5\zeta(4)+4\zeta(6)), \\
 &\textrm{ since }(x+1)(x+2)(x+4)(x+5)=(x+3)^4-5(x+3)^2+4,\\
I_7&=14\left((1-1/2^2)\zeta(2)-35(1-1/2^4)\zeta(4)+259(1-1/2^6)\zeta(6)-225(1-1/2^8)\zeta(8)\right), \\
& \textrm{ since }2^6(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)\\
&\qquad \qquad =(2x+7)^6-35(2x+7)^4+259(2x+7)^2-225,\\
I_8&=4(\zeta(2)-14\zeta(4)+49\zeta(6)-36\zeta(8)),\\
 & \textrm{ since } (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+5)(x+6)(x+7)\\
 &\qquad \qquad =(x+4)^6-14(x+4)^4+49(x+4)^2-36
\end{array}$$

**Proof of the claim:**
This should be a consequence of Quanto's nice answer. But here we start from
the formula in J.G's comment
$$ I_n=n!2^n\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{(2k+n)^{n+1}}\binom{n+k-1}{k}.$$
The following is just an exercise after J.G's comment.

First assume that $n=2m$ is even. Then we can write
$$(2m-1)!\binom{x+2m-1}{2m-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A^n_j (x+m)^{2m-2j-1}.$$
Thus
$$\begin{array}{ll}I_n&=m\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{(k+m)^{2m+1}}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A_j^n(k+m)^{2m-2j-1}\\
&=m\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A_j^n\frac{1}{(k+m)^{2j+2}}\\
&=m\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_j A_j^n \frac{1}{k^{2j+2}}\\
&=m\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} A_j^n \zeta(2j+2).
\end{array}
$$
Note that $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A_j^n(x+m)^{2m-2j-2}=0$ for $x=-1,\dots,-(m-1)$, since $-1,\dots,-(m-1)$ are roots of
$$(2m-1)!\binom{x+2m-1}{2m-1}/(x+m)=(x+2m-1)\dots \widehat{(x+m)}(x+(m-1))\dots (x+1).$$
The above equation is the same as $$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A^n_j l^{2m-2j-2}=0, l=1,2,\dots,m-1.$$
Thus we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A_j^n\frac{1}{l^{2j+2}}=0, l=1,2,\dots, m-1, $$
which implies
$$m\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}A_j^n\frac{1}{(k+m)^{2j+2}}\\
=m\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_j A_j^n \frac{1}{k^{2j+2}},$$
one step we used in the above calculation.

Next, consider the case when $n=2m+1$ is odd. There are integers $A^n_0=1,A^n_1,A^n_2,\dots, A^n_m$ such that
$$(*)\qquad 2^{2m}(2m)!\binom{x+2m}{2m}=(2x+2m+1)^{2m}+A^m_1(2x+2m+1)^{2m-2}+\dots+A^m_m\\
=\sum_{j=0}^m A^n_j (2x+2m+1)^{2m-2j}.
$$
holds as a polynomial of $x$. This is because the polynomial $(x+2m)\cdots (x+1)$ is symmetric about the line $x=m+1/2$.

Thus
$$\begin{array}{ll}
I_{2m+1}&=2(2m+1)\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{(2k+2m+1)^{2m+2}}\left(2^{2m}(2m)!\binom{k+2m}{2m} \right)\\
&=2(2m+1)\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\sum_{j=0}^m \frac{A^n_j}{(2k+2m+1)^{2+2j}} \right)\\
&=2(2m+1)\sum_{k\ge 0}\left( \sum_{j=0}^mA^n_j \frac{1}{(2k+1)^{2+2j}}\right)\\
&=2(2m+1)\sum_{j=0}^m\left(A^n_j(1-\frac{1}{2^{2+2j}})\zeta(2+2j)). \right)
\end{array}$$
where we used $$\sum_{j=1}^m A_j^n(2k+2m+1)^{2m-2j}=0, k=-1,-2,\dots,-m.$$

Comment: Thanks for this very interesting solution. Could you elaborate on the change from $\frac{1}{(k+m)^{2j+2}}$ to $\frac{1}{k^{2j+2}}$? It's a bit unclear currently why $m$ would be negative and what $\sum_{j=1}^m$ means for negative $m$. It seems to me the argument is that the $k\ge 0$ sum can start at $-(k-1)$?

Comment: @heiner Thanks for your comment. There should be a typo is the previous version. See the new edit and hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: Just by curiosity: do you think some parts of your solution could be written more concisely using umbral calculus?

Comment: @Wolfgang Sorry, I am not familiar with umbral calculus. But it should be. It is just an exercise after J.G's comment.

Comment: For even $n$ the coefficients $A_j^n$ of $\zeta(2k+2)$ relate to the "central factorial numbers" (OEIS [A008955](https://oeis.org/A008955)):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2I_2/2 \\
2I_4/4 \\
2I_6/6 \\
2I_8/8 \\
2I_{10}/10 \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&    0&    0&    0&    0 & \cdots \\
   1&   -1&    0&    0&    0 \\
   1&   -5&    4&    0&    0 \\
   1&  -14&   49&  -36&    0 \\
   1&  -30&  273& -820&  576 \\
   \vdots &&&&&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\zeta(2) \\
\zeta(4) \\
\zeta(6) \\
\zeta(8) \\
\zeta(10) \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Or generally for $2I_{2m}/{(2m)} = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} t(2m, 2m-2k)\zeta(2k+2)$ with $t(2n,2k)$ the even central factorial numbers (of the first kind).

This is of interest to me because $I_n/n$ should be summable and I would be interested if there's a closed form expression for it, as it relates to another integral I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2):

This is a remark continuing from J.G.'s hint and Q. Zhang's solution.

For even $n$ the coefficients $A_j^n$ of $\zeta(2k+2)$ relate to the "central factorial numbers" (OEIS [A008955](https://oeis.org/A008955)):

$$
2\begin{pmatrix}
I_2/2 \\
I_4/4 \\
I_6/6 \\
I_8/8 \\
I_{10}/10 \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&    \hfill0&    \hfill0&    \hfill0&    \hfill0 & \cdots \\
   1&   \hfill-1&   \hfill 0&  \hfill  0&  \hfill  0 \\
   1&   \hfill-5&   \hfill 4&  \hfill  0&  \hfill  0 \\
   1&  \hfill-14&   \hfill49&  \hfill-36&  \hfill  0 \\
   1&  -30&  273& -820&  576 \\
   \vdots &&&&&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\zeta(2) \\
\zeta(4) \\
\zeta(6) \\
\zeta(8) \\
\zeta(10) \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$

or generally $2I_{2m}/{(2m)} = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} t(2m, 2m-2k)\zeta(2k+2)$ with $t(2n,2k)$ the even central factorial numbers (of the first kind), see OEIS [A008955](https://oeis.org/A008955).

For odd $n$ such a relation holds as well, namely
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_1 /1 \\
I_3 /3 \\
I_5 /5 \\
I_7 /7 \\
I_9 /9 \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&    \hfill 0&    \hfill 0&   \hfill  0&   \hfill  0 & \cdots \\
     1&   \hfill -1&    \hfill 0&   \hfill  0&  \hfill   0 \\
     1&   \hfill-10&    \hfill 9&  \hfill   0&  \hfill   0 \\  
     1&   \hfill-35&  \hfill 259& \hfill -225&  \hfill   0 \\  
     1&   \hfill-84&  1974&-12916& 11025 \\
  \vdots &&&&&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
(1-2^{-2})\zeta(2) \\
(1-2^{-4})\zeta(4) \\
(1-2^{-6})\zeta(6) \\
(1-2^{-8})\zeta(8) \\
(1-2^{-10})\zeta(10) \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix},
$$

i.e.,
$I_{2m+1}/(2m+1) = 2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} 4^k t(2m+1,2m+1-2k)(1 - \frac{1}{2^{2k+2}})\zeta(2k+2)$ with $t(2n+1,2k+1)$ the odd central factorial numbers, see OEIS [A008956](https://oeis.org/A008956).

This is of interest to me because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n/n$ should exist and I would be interested if there's a closed form expression for it, as it relates to another integral I'm interested in, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096986/int-0-infty-log-left1-fracx-sinh-x-right-dx-and-generalisations).

To prove the relations above, one way is to note that Q. Zhang's coefficients can be expressed via [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_roots_of_a_polynomial) as elementary symmetric polynomials. If $e_j^n$ is the $j$th elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $n$ evaluated at $1^2,\ldots,n^2$, the recursion $e_j^n = e_j^{n-1} + n^2 e_{j-1}^{n-1}$ holds. Comparing to the recursion formulae for the central factorial numbers (i.e., in OEIS or in [Butzer et al.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01630568908816313)), the claim follows for even $n$. The case for odd $n$ can be shown along similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just a corollary :

Using :

$$x^n/(\sinh(x))^n=2^nx^n\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(2n+1)x}\right)^n$$

Then use [Series expansion of infinite series raised to the $n$th power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782316/series-expansion-of-infinite-series-raised-to-the-nth-power)

The sum and the result above in other answer are equal and could be express in term of [Wright](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) function