# $\int_0^\infty \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)\,dx$ and generalisations

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, gamma-function, hyperbolic-functions

I'm interested in the value of

$$
\theta(2) := -\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^\infty \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)\,dx.
$$

I have some hopes this admits a closed-form solution. Expanding the logarithm yields the integral $I_n := \int_0^\infty(\frac{x}{\sinh x})^n\,dx$, which has [recently been asked about here on math.sa](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4080397/5051).

More generally, I'd love to know a closed-form solution for

$$\theta(\ell) := -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \log\left(1 - \left\lvert \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\ell}{2}+ix)}{\Gamma(\frac{\ell}{2})}\right\rvert^2\right)\,dx$$

with $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$. For $\ell=2$ this is the same integral as above; see below for details.

The integral $\theta(\ell)$ has some relation to the eigenvalues of truncated random orthogonal matrices; see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.03154.pdf#page=29), especially equation (7.1).

Some partial results below.

---

For $\ell=1$, the integral $\theta(1)$ is solvable by expanding the $\log$ and its value is

$$\theta(1) = \frac{3}{16}.$$

Note that for $b\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$
\left|\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}+bi\right)\right|^2  = \frac{\pi}{\cosh \pi b}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\left|\Gamma\left(1+bi\right)\right|^2 = \frac{\pi b}{\sinh \pi b},
$$

or more generally for $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\Gamma\left(1+n+bi\right)\right|^2 & = \frac{\pi b}{\sinh \pi b} \prod_{k=1}^n \left(k^2 + b^2 \right)\\
\left|\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2} + n+bi\right)\right|^2 & = \frac{\pi}{\cosh \pi b} \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\left( k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 + b^2 \right)
\end{align}$$

(for a derivation, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General)). Hence, when expanding the $\log$ the integral turns into the sum of the integral of powers of $\frac{1}{\sinh}$ and $\frac{1}{\cosh}$ times a polynomial.

For instance for $\ell=2$, one has

$$2\pi^2\theta(2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty \Bigl(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\Bigr)^n\,dx.$$

The integral $I_n := \int_0^\infty(\frac{x}{\sinh x})^n\,dx$ has [recently been asked about here on math.sa](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4080397/5051). The answers prove a recurrence relation and indicate that $I_n$ is a linear combination of $\zeta(2), \zeta(4), \ldots, \zeta(2⌈n/2⌉)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where the coefficients are the "central factorial numbers", see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4094829/5051). (The central factorial numbers (OEIS [A008955](https://oeis.org/A008955) and [A008956](https://oeis.org/A008956)) turn out to also show up in the power series expansion of $x\mapsto(\frac{x}{\sinh x})^n$, $x\mapsto(\arcsin x)^n$ and powers of various other trigonometric functions; see [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01630568908816313) for a thorough treatment.)

I'd be interested to know if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}I_n$ admits a more succinct representation.

For larger values of $\ell$, the expansion produces terms of the form $\int_0^\infty x^n(\frac{1}{\sinh x})^m \, dx$ and $\int_0^\infty x^n(\frac{1}{\cosh x})^m \, dx$. In the [question mentioned before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4080397/5051), user Quanto has given a recurrence relation for such integrals. The polynomials in question make it likely central factorial numbers play a role in the linear combinations there too.

Comment: An idea for the case $\ell=2$ might be to compute
$$
\int_0^\infty \log\big(1-\frac x {\sinh(x)}\big) dx
= 
\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac x {\sinh(x) -\lambda x} d\lambda dx. 
$$
Now $\sinh(x) -\lambda x\geq 0$ and we write 
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac x {\sinh(x) -\lambda x} d\lambda dx = 
\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty x e^{-t(\sinh(x) -\lambda x)} d\lambda dx dt.
$$
Performing the $\lambda$ integration
$$\int_0^\infty \log\big(1-\frac x {\sinh(x)}\big) dx
=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-t\sinh(x)}\frac {e^{x t} -1}t dx dt.$$
How to continue form here, I don't know.

Comment: $$\theta(2) := -\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^\infty \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)\,dx.$$ to make it equivalent to the log gamma integral.

Comment: @JamesArathoon: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: A couple of equivalent integrals for $\theta(2)$ $$\theta(2) :=\frac{1}{2 \pi ^2}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{z\, (1-z \coth (z)) \text{csch}(z)}{z\, \text{csch}(z)-1} \, dz$$
$$\theta(2) :=\frac{1}{2 \pi ^2}\int_0^1 \frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}(t) \left(\left(t^2+1\right) \tanh ^{-1}(t)-t\right)}{t \left(\left(t^2-1\right) \tanh ^{-1}(t)+t\right)} \, dt$$

Comment: A deleted answer suggested starting from $\int_0^\infty \ln(1-e^{-2x})\,dx = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}$, but didn't lead to a solution either.

Comment: On the topic of unsuccessful attempts: By using the power series for $(2\arcsin(x/2))^{2m}$, which is (4.1.4) in [Butzer et al](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01630568908816313), one can show that the "even part" of $\theta(2)$ can be expressed as the horrible $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^x-1} \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j (2j)! \frac{d^{2j-1}}{dx^{2j-1}} (2\arcsin\frac{ix}{2})^{2j}\,dx$.

Comment: As the deleted answer pointed out, solving the $\theta(2)$ integral is equivalent to solving $\int_0^\infty \log(1 - 2xe^{-x} - e^{-2x})\,dx$. The latter integral doesn't seem to be known either.

Answer (score 5):

I will illustrate why it is unlikely a closed form in elementary functions exists.

Let $$I=\int_0^\infty\log\left(1-\frac x{\sinh x}\right)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x(x\coth x-1)}{x-\sinh x}\,dx$$ on integration by parts. In exponential notation, we have $$I=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^x((x-1)e^{2x}+x+1)}{(e^{2x}-1)(e^{2x}-2xe^x-1)}\,dx$$ where we use the fact that the integrand $f(x)$ is even.

Taking a semicircular contour on the upper half plane, we have $$I=2\pi i\left(\sum_{k>0}\underbrace{\operatorname{Res}(f,ik\pi)}_{e^{2z}-1\,\text{contribution}}+\sum_j\underbrace{\operatorname{Res}(f,w_j)}_{\text{where}\,e^{2w_j}-2w_je^{w_j}=1}\right)$$ since the arc contribution $$\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_0^\pi iRe^{i\theta}f(Re^{i\theta})\,d\theta=\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_0^\pi iRe^{i\theta}\frac{Re^{i\theta}(Re^{i\theta}-1)+O(1)}{e^{Re^{i\theta}}-2Re^{i\theta}+O(1)}\,d\theta=0$$ vanishes due to the dominant exponential term on the denominator.

By direct computation we can show that $\operatorname{Res}(f,ik\pi)=-ik\pi/2$ for a positive integer $k$. However, this cannot be said for the roots $w_j$ of $e^{2z}-2ze^z-1$. Upon writing $w_j=x+iy$, we obtain a system of highly transcendental equations \begin{align}e^{2x}\cos2y-2e^x(x\cos y-y\sin y)&=1\\(e^x\sin y+x\tan y+y)\cos y&=0\end{align} which appears to have [infinitely many solutions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ojattjsz9b); note that theoretically there must be infinitely many since they need to cancel out with the divergent sum $\sum\limits_{k>0}\operatorname{Res}(f,ik\pi)$. So unless there is a miraculous simplification of this system, it is extremely unlikely we can obtain a closed form for $\sum\limits_j\operatorname{Res}(f,w_j)$ in elementary functions, and hence for $I$.

Comment: (+1) The integral is a sum of roots of a transcendental equation. Is there a way to show this result without the residue theorem nor contour integrals?

Comment: One can show the integral is a series of values of the form $\zeta(2n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where the series is not absolutely convergent, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4081308/5051. The coefficients involved are the so-called central factorial numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to solve the question for $\ell = 2$ first it might be easier to solve the question for $\ell = 3,5,7,9,...$ as all of these result in integrals involving $\cosh(x)$ and for $l=1$ one can solve it.

For $\ell=3$ one can do the following:
$$
\left| \frac{\Gamma(\frac 3 2 + i x)}{\Gamma(\frac 3 2)} \right|^2
=
\left| \frac{\Gamma(\frac 1 2 + i x)}{\Gamma(\frac 1 2)} \right|^2 (1+ 4 x^2) 
= \frac 1 {\cosh(\pi x)} (1 + 4 x^2).
$$
Using this and expaning the logarithm, we get
$$
-\int_0^\infty dx \log \left( 1 - \left| \frac{\Gamma(\frac 3 2 + i x)}{\Gamma(\frac 3 2)} \right|^2\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac 1 n \int_0^\infty dx (1 + 4x^2)^n \frac 1 {\cosh^n(\pi x)}. 
$$
Now we use the following identity (Gradshtein/Ryzhik eq. 3.512, which is also true for $b=0$)
$$
\int_0^\infty dx \frac{\cosh(2 b x)}{\cosh^{2v}(ax)} = \frac {4^{v-1}} a B\left(v+ \frac b a, v - \frac b a\right)
$$
where $B(\ ,\ )$ is the Beta function. We further note that
$$
\frac {d^{2k}}{d b^{2k}} \cosh(2bx)\big|_{b=0} = (4x)^{2k}.
$$
Not bothering about any convergence and expanding $(1+4x^2)^n$, this implies
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty dx (1 + 4x^2)^n \frac 1 {\cosh^n(\pi x)}
&= 
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\int_0^\infty dx \frac { \frac {d^{2k}}{d b^{2k}} \cosh(2bx)\big|_{b=0}} {\cosh^n(\pi x)} \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 
\frac{4^{n/2-1}} \pi \frac {d^{2k}}{d b^{2k}}  B\left(\frac n 2 + \frac  b \pi, \frac n 2 - \frac b \pi \right)\big|_{b=0}.
\end{align}
Writing the Beta function in terms of the $\Gamma$ function and rearranging the summations a little, we end up with
\begin{align}
&-\int_0^\infty dx \log \left( 1 - \left| \frac{\Gamma(\frac 3 2 + i x)}{\Gamma(\frac 3 2)} \right|^2\right) \\
=&
\frac 1 \pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ d^{2k}}{d b^{2k}} \left(\sum_{n: n\geq \max\{k,1\}} \frac {4^{\frac n 2 -1}}{k! (n-k)!} \Gamma\left(\frac n 2 +\frac b \pi\right) \Gamma\left(\frac n 2 -\frac b \pi\right)\right)\Big|_{b = 0} \\
=&
\frac 1 \pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {4^{k/2}}{k!}\frac{ d^{2k}}{d b^{2k}} \left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac {4^{\frac n 2 -1}}{n!} \Gamma\left(\frac {n+k} 2 +\frac b \pi\right) \Gamma\left(\frac {n + k} 2  -\frac b \pi\right)\right)\Big|_{b = 0}
.
\end{align}
This is not a complete answer but maybe a step in the right direction? Similar calculations work for all odd $\ell$.