# Integral of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik: $\int_0^\infty\ln(1 + 2e^{-x}\cos t + e^{-2x})\,dx =\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{t^2}2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm looking for a proof of identity 4.223.3 from [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's Tables of Integrals, Series and Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradshteyn_and_Ryzhik), namely

$$\int_0^\infty\ln(1 + 2e^{-x}\cos t + e^{-2x})\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{t^2}{2} \qquad (\lvert t\rvert < \pi)$$

(I suspect it holds for $\lvert t\rvert = \pi$ as well).

Unlike the proceeding formulas 4.223.1 and 4.223.2 for $\int_0^\infty\ln(1 \pm e^{-x})\,dx$, its proof does not appear in [part 9 of Amdeberhan et al.'s Integrals in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.2124v1.pdf#page=3). The reference in GR is for table 256 of the 1867 work *Nouvelles tables d'intégrales définies* ([large pdf](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/bitstream/handle/1774.2/121/Jhu_NouvellesTablesD%27integralesDefines_L_752pgs.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y)).

One reason I'm interested in the derivation is that the integral looks related to

$$\int_0^\infty \ln(1 - 2xe^{-x} - e^{-2x})\,dx,$$

which is equivalent to the integral asked in a [previous unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096986/int-0-infty-log-left1-fracx-sinh-x-right-dx-and-generalisations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach is to notice that the integral is
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{ + \infty } {\log \left| {1 + e^{ - (x + it)} } \right|^2 dx}  = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\Re \log (1 + e^{ - (x + it)} )dx} \\ & = 2\Re \int_0^{ + \infty } {\log (1 + e^{ - (x + it)} )dx}  = 2\Re \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{e^{ - (x + it)n} }}{n}} dx} \\ & = 2\Re \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} e^{ - i nt  } }}{n}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nx} dx} } \\ & = 2\Re \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{e^{ - itn} }}{{n^2 }}}  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{\cos (nt)}}{{n^2 }}} 
\end{align*}
which is the Fourier series of $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{t^2}{2}$, $|t|<\pi$.

Answer (score 6):

Let the given integeral be $I(t)$. Differentiating wrt $t$,

$$I'(t) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{-2e^{-x}\sin t}{1+2e^{-x}\cos t+e^{-2x}}dx$$

Substitute $e^{-x} = y \Rightarrow -e^{-x}dx = dy$, then

$$I'(t) = -\int_0^1 \frac{2\sin t}{1+2y\cos t +y^2}dy $$

Using $\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1$,

$$I'(t) = -2\sin t\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(y + \cos t)^2 + \sin^2 t}dy = -2\sin t\left(\frac{1}{\sin t} \arctan\left(\frac{y + \cos t}{\sin t}\right)\right|_0^1$$

$$\Rightarrow I'(t) = -2\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1 + \cos t}{\sin t}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}\right)\right)$$

With $1 + \cos t = 2\cos^2 \frac{t}{2}$, $\sin t = 2\sin\frac{t}{2}\cos\frac{t}{2}$ and $\arctan t = \frac{\pi}{2} - \cot^{-1}t$, the above expression is

$$I'(t) = -t \Rightarrow I(t) = \frac{-t^2}{2} + c$$

To determine $c$, we need to calculate $I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. From the original integral,

$$I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \int_0^{\infty} \ln(1 + e^{-2x})dx = \frac{\pi^2}{24}$$

The above result is available in the linked pdf itself. Thereforce,

$$c = I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Hence,

$$I(t) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{t^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

This is really a slight expansion on the comment by Masacroso: If you make the substitution $\exp(-t) = u,$ and then differentiate with respect to $t,$ you get a rational function integral, which is easy to evaluate. For the starting point, the obvious value is $t=\frac{\pi}{2},$ which gets rid of the cosine term.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

\begin{align}
I(t)=&\int_0^\infty\ln(1 + 2e^{-x}\cos t + e^{-2x})\,dx \\
=&2Re \int_0^\infty\ln(1+e^{it-x})dx 
\overset{y=e^{it-x} }
=2Re \int_{0}^{e^{it}} \frac{\ln(1+y)}y dy\\
I’(t) =& 2Re\>( i \ln (1+e^{it}))=2Re\> \left(i\ln\left(2\cos\frac t2 e^{i \frac t2}\right)\right)=-t
\end{align}
Then
$$I(t)= I(0)+\int_0^t I’(s)ds
= 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+y)}ydy-\int_0^t s\>ds= \frac{\pi^2}6 -\frac {t^2}2
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch for possible solution, too long for a comment:** suppose we can differentiate under the integral sign, then if $I(t)$ is the original integral
$$
\frac{d}{dt}I(t)=-2\sin t\int_0^{\infty }\frac1{e^x+2\cos t+e^{-x}}\mathop{}\!d x
$$

Then setting $c_t:=2\cos t,\, s_t:=-2\sin t$ and with the change of variable $e^x=y$ you have that

$$
\frac{d}{dt}I(t)=s_t\int_1^{\infty }\frac1{y^2+c_t y+1}\mathop{}\!d y
$$

Then the last integral is solvable in two different ways depending on the value of $c_t$. This would give a closed form for $\frac{d}{dt}I(t)$. Now the integral $I(0)$ seems attackable, thus you will have finally a first order linear differential equation, what "probably" can be solved explicitly.